# Xcode9 unable to enter Git username while git pull

Tags: ios, github, version-control, xcode9, git-pull

I am working on an app where I am pulling my code from the remote git repository While doing this Xcode not allowing me to enter my GitHub username. Its showing 'git' as prefill disable username. Please check attached screenshot link for same.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because the repo is private and you need to introduce it's password?

Comment: Thanks, fo the reply..! you are right repo is private, But my username is not listing there git is not my username. After entering correct password it's giving me an invalid credential error.

Comment: Try entering the repo's password that you get when you create it.

Comment: After entering the right password I am getting an error -  Authentication failed because the name or password was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand going to : https://github.com/contact and write them a message that you want to change the password and they will help you trough that for sure!

Comment: Actually, my password is right because I am able to login with the same password on the web.

Comment: The will surelly be able to fix any problem :) Maybe it's on their side

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch to the HTTPS remote URL.

```
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/myUserName/myProject.git
```